# Add a "Copy this row" context menu to agGrid

Tags: ag-grid-angular

I would like to add a "Copy this row to the clipboard" context menu item to my agGrid (running in Angular 9).

agGrid gives us a "`params`" value, containing the currently selected value, and, `params.node.data`, which contains the "raw" entire record for this row.

```
getContextMenuItems(params) {
    return [
      {
        name: 'Copy this row',
        action: function() {
          let dataForThisRecord = params.node.data;

          //  ...what now...?
      },
      'export'    //  This adds the generic agGrid "export\export to Excel" menu items
    ];
}
```

The problem is, my `params.node.data` is huge, and my agGrid is actually just displaying 5 fields of this record, so I just want these 5 fields (in the same order as in the grid).

Also, some of those 5 agGrids columns might have valueGetter functions or cellRenderers, so I want to get the values *after* these have been called.

So, rather than exporting the raw data, which I can see in the `params.node.data` object:

```
{
   forename: 'Mike',
   surname: 'Jones',
   DOB: '2020-04-30T00:00:00',
   countryID: 1001,
   phone: '055 123 4567'
}
```

I want to copy the values *as they are shown in the grid*, after passing through any cellRenderers or valueGetters:

```
[ 'Mike', 'Jones', '30/4/2020', 'France', '055 123 4567' ]
```

Is is possible to do this ?

I assume so, as when I add a default 'export' option to my context menu, agGrid itself will happily export my data into an Excel file, containing the nicely-formatted values which are shown in the grid.

Answer (score 1):

There is no correct way, and it cannot be, because the render returns html.
Workarounds below.

**Clipboard Api in deph**

```
export interface IClipboardService {
    registerGridCore(gridCore: GridCore): void;
    pasteFromClipboard(): void;
    copyToClipboard(includeHeader?: boolean): void;
    copySelectedRowsToClipboard(includeHeader?: boolean, columnKeys?: (string | Column)[]): void;
    copySelectedRangeToClipboard(includeHeader?: boolean): void;
    copyRangeDown(): void;
}
```

Look at `ClipboardService` from enterprise.
In private `ClipboardService.copyFocusedCellToClipboard` get value from `gridOptions.processCellForClipboard`.

Set `gridOptions.processCellForClipboard = (params) => myLogic(params.node.data, params.column.colDef.field)`.
Then select row as `params.node.setSelected(true)`. 
Then `params.api.copySelectedRowsToClipboard(false, columnKeys)`

**All render pipline methods in colDef, not in api but!**

Formatter `valueFormatterService` not exists in GridApi. But `valueGetter` exists as `params.api.getValue`.

**TLDR**

```
action: function() {
   const colDef = params.column.getColDef();
   // do
   const value = colDef.valueGetter(...);
   // or do 
   const value = params.api.getValue(colDef.colId, params.node); // valueGetter
   // then
   params.api.clipboardService.copyDataToClipboard(value);
},
```

**Warn**

The first method works through selection, it’s bad, because the user will suffer.

The second method requires playing the pipeline.

In total, I came to the fact that I wrote my own handler for working with the console, so that the format in Excel and in the clipboard often do not match.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to write is:

```
{
    name: 'Details for... ',
    disabled: true,
},
'separator',
'copy',
'copyWithHeaders',
'copyWithGroupHeaders',
'separator'
```

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/context-menu/

Comment: Nope, sorry... you've missed the point of the question.  If I have a date column, but have added a CellRenderer to display it as, say, "dd/mm/yyyy", then "copyWithHeaders" will export the *raw* data (eg "2022-04-26T10.23:45") rather than what's actually being shown in the grid ("26 April, 2022")